# Default configuration in Play 2.0 causes IOException?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is this a bug with the default configuration of Play 2.0? I have just installed Play 2.0 and when I create an application for the first time, I get this:

```
Error during sbt execution: java.io.IOException: Cannot write parent directory: Path(/home/hanxue/play/myFirstApp/app) of /home/hanxue/play/myFirstApp/app/views
```

The app subdirectory does not have write permissions:

```
hanxue@ubuntu-dev:~/play$ ls -l myFirstApp/
total 16
dr-xr-xr-x 2 hanxue hanxue 4096 2012-03-13 11:22 app
```

It also seems that the **$PLAY/framework/sbt/boot/** directory need to be world-writable or otherwise play will throw an IOException about not being able to create **/opt/play-2.0/framework/sbt/boot/sbt.boot.lock** . Is this by design?

I solved it by giving it world-writable permission

```
chmod -R o+w /opt/play-2.0/framework/sbt/boot/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, it is just how sbt works(and play-2.0 uses sbt). Sbt downloads all necessary parts first time when its started, and default behavior of play is that all dependency go to same directory and this is place where you extracted play-2.0, so this directory needs write permissions.  You will probably need write permissions on /opt/play-2.0/repository too.

Comment: Is there any way to change the default behavior? I tried to modify [boot]
  directory: ${play.home}/sbt/boot
from /play-2.1.5/framework/sbt/sb.boot.properties but it didn't work.